# Debug and step through addon?

Tags: python, scripting, export, add-on

I've installed the DirectX export addon (found [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/DirectX_Exporter)). I'm exporting an object with armature animation but it's not working how I expect it to and the documentation isn't helpful (See [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12124/directx-exporter-does-the-currently-selected-action-make-a-difference)).

Since the addon is just a Python script, is there a way to set a breakpoint in the code and step through the exporter script like a debugger? I've looked a this [similar question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2502/can-i-run-a-python-script-step-by-step-in-blender) but running the Blender interactive Python console, I can't set my export options for the exporter, so it fails when I try to run the 'export' command.

I'm hoping there's something like the following:

1. Open Blender normally (by double-clicking the Blender shortcut on my desktop)
2. Enable some sort of Python debugging mode
3. Open the file I'd like to export.
4. Click File > Export > DirectX
5. Choose my export options and filename
6. Click Export DirectX
7. Blender brings me into a code window showing the exporter script and it's paused on the first line, waiting for me to step through the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Free & Open Source software, using Eclipse and PyDev.

- Download & install Eclipse from https://eclipse.org/downloads/
- Follow PyDev installation manual http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html
- Install my [remote debugging add-on](https://github.com/sybrenstuvel/random-blender-addons/blob/master/remote_debugger.py) from Github
- Configure it in the addon preferences for /home/sybren/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev_5.3.0.201610121612/pysrc/pydevd.py (adjust for your system)
- Start a debug server in PyDev
- Press Space in the 3D view and search for "pydev", then choose the operator to connect to the PyDev debugger.

You can see me explaining the steps in my Blender Conference 2016 talk [Develop add-ons like a pro](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=mYrPqrFY7mA).